# WPF - How to apply converter to all DataGridTextColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, converters

I would like using WPF Apply Converter to Binding Value to all DataGridTextColumn in application.

For single DataGridTextColumn converter working fine:

```
<DataGridTextColumn 
    Header ="Value" 
    Binding="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource decimalConverter}}" 
    />
```

But in application I got many (over 100) DataGridTextColumn in different DataGrid's and I would know best solution for that instead of applying for each columns converter separately.

I know using Style there is possibility to modify some property for all Type of controls (e.g. foreground) but not sure how use these for the Binding Value and Converter?

Comment: In my case when a similar problem arose, I ended up modifying each one like in your sample, then chassing down any leftover. Boring and error prone, but can't think of anything better with WPF.

Comment: So you want to add one converter too all DataGridTextColumn.Bindings, even non-decimal?

Comment: Styling a DataGridTextColumn isn't that easy.
[DataGridTextColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtextcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx)  does not inherit from FrameworkElement.

Comment: Yes, and to clarify in these application I have only decimal DataGridTextColumns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the help of global style and attached property. You cannot create global style (or any style) for `DataGridTextColumn` because it does not inherit from `FrameworkElement`. But you can create style for `DataGrid` itself, set attached property for grid in that style, and in property changed handler of that attached property set converter for all column bindings when they are added. Sample code:

```
public class DataGridHelper : DependencyObject {
    public static IValueConverter GetConverter(DependencyObject obj) {
        return (IValueConverter) obj.GetValue(ConverterProperty);
    }

    public static void SetConverter(DependencyObject obj, IValueConverter value) {
        obj.SetValue(ConverterProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ConverterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Converter", typeof(IValueConverter), typeof(DataGridHelper), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnConverterChanged));

    private static void OnConverterChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        // here we have our converter
        var converter = (IValueConverter) e.NewValue;
        // first modify binding of all existing columns if any
        foreach (var column in ((DataGrid) d).Columns.OfType<DataGridTextColumn>()) {
            if (column.Binding != null && column.Binding is Binding)
            {
                ((Binding)column.Binding).Converter = converter;
            }
        }
        // then subscribe to columns changed event and modify binding of all added columns
        ((DataGrid) d).Columns.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) => {
            if (args.NewItems != null) {
                foreach (var column in args.NewItems.OfType<DataGridTextColumn>()) {
                    if (column.Binding != null && column.Binding is Binding) {
                        ((Binding) column.Binding).Converter = converter;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then create global style somewhere (like App.xaml):

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:TestConverter x:Key="decimalConverter" />
    <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="local:DataGridHelper.Converter"
                Value="{StaticResource decimalConverter}" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly fine for me! Thanks for quick solution.